# Making a tree of Wikipedia links

Tags: graph, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am trying to use the Wikipedia API to get all links on all pages. Currently I'm using

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=alllinks&prop=links&pllimit=max&plnamespace=0

but this does not seem to start at the first article and end at the last. How can I get this to generate all pages and all their links?

Comment: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/

Comment: You'd want `generator=allpages` but you probably don't want to use that to cycle through all forty million pages of the English Wikipedia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The English Wikipedia has approximately 1.05 billion internal links. Considering the `list=alllinks` module has a limit of 500 links per request, it's not realistic to get all links from the API.

Instead, you can download [Wikipedia's database dumps](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/) and use those. Specifically, you want the `pagelinks` dump, containing information about the links themselves, and very likely also the `page` dump, for mapping page ids to page titles.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone else is searching and finds this, I highly recommend looking at [Wikicrush](https://github.com/trishume/wikicrush) to extract the link graph for all of Wikipedia. It produces a relatively compact representation that can be used to very quickly traverse links.